# Cannot SSH over the internet even port forwarded

Tags: networking, server, ssh, port-forwarding

I can SSH via local network.

```
nmap -p <ssh_port> 192.168.1.xx => <ssh_port> open
```

But I can't SSH over the internet even port forwarded.

```
nmap -p <ssh_port> xxxx.duckdns.org or <public_ip> => <ssh_port> closed
```

And I also have another port forwarding to  and it work find over the internet.

```
nmap -p <cctv_port> xxxx.duckdns.org or <public_ip> => <cctv_port> open
```

How do I check what is the problems (my ubuntu, router, duckdns or ISP) ? and How to fix it ?

Update1:

- I contact to my ISP and thay told they doesn't block any ports.
- Now I try using python3 -m http.server 8181 and do port forward but can't access from outside too.

Comment: Some ISP block some common ports. You may try to change to use other ports.

Comment: I also try some other ports but still closed.

Comment: Now I try to use SSH port with working cctv_port. But port not open.

Comment: seems problem at router, if ssh working fine within LAN.

Comment: Are you trying from inside your own network, to the external address? Not all routers support [hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning). Try from outside your network, or get a friend to try for you.

Comment: Thanks @vidarlo I also try from outside network using DigitalOcean VPS and http://canyouseeme.org/ But still can't access ports.

Comment: Probably you are behind a double nat. So in short words for solutiom you need an intermidiare ssh server (most of cheep wehosting are suitable) then you ssh to  this hosting from work and do reverse ssh tunnel to work comp. Then from home do connect to that hosting with open ssh tunnel to work and you would be able to use your work comp ssh shell. (Thanks to those who correct  my comment)

Comment: Thanks, @Yurij May be my server is on double NAT. I will recheck and notify to you all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I configured port forwarding wrong.
On some huawei router (eg. HG8247H) you need to set external ports mapping to the internal ports, But I forgot to set external ports for some rules.

It's makes my router wrong port mapping behavier. (eg. client request access to port xxx, but client get access to port yyy that is on a previous rules)

I fixed it by **add external port on each rules**.